# Two While Loops in one html table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, html-table

I have two SQL tables:

- News
- Editors

In News table, I have 2 colums (News_Added and News_Updated). I am entering Editor IDs to these columns and joining them to Editors table's Ed_ID to get Editor names.

Since I have 2 while queries I have to use 2 while loops, but in 1 html table. I don't know how to solve this problem. Any help?

```
echo '<table border="0">
<tr><th>News ID</th><th>Title</th><th>Added By</th><th>Last Edit By</th><th>Action</th</tr>';

$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM N1News AS N1
LEFT JOIN A1Editors AS A1 ON N1.N1_Addedby=A1.Ed_ID WHERE N1_Co=$Ed_Co ORDER BY N1_ID LIMIT $show,$limit");
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
    echo '<tr><td align="center">'.$row["N1_ID"].'</td><td><a href="news_edit2.php?n_id='.$row["N1_ID"].'">'.$row["N1_Title"].'</a></td>
    <td><a href="news_edit2.php?n_id='.$row['N1_ID'].'"><img src="images/icons/hammer_screwdriver.png" alt="Edit News" /></a><a href="news_del.php?n_id='.$row["N1_ID"].'"><img src="images/icons/cross.png" alt="Delete News" /></a></td><td>'.$row["Ed_Name"].'</td>';
}
$query7 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM N1News AS N1
LEFT JOIN A1Editors AS A1 ON N1.N1_Lastedit=A1.Ed_ID WHERE N1_Co=$Ed_Co ORDER BY N1_ID LIMIT $show,$limit");
    while($row7 = mysql_fetch_array($query7)){
    echo '<td>'.$row7["Ed_Name"].'</td>';
    }
```

Comment: Are you trying to add the editor's name to each result row? Or list them in a separate table entirely? I'm not 100% sure what you're trying to achieve here.

Comment: So you got 2 queries, and 2 corresponding while loops for those queries, so whats the problem?

Comment: It's a table which lists all news. And table colums are; News ID, News Title, Added By, Edited By, Action(edit,delete)

Comment: coder1984, it's an html problem, since there are 2 queries, I have a problem to use <tr> tags.

Comment: No, the problem is that you're outputting things before you have all information available. First gather all the information, then output to wherever it should go. Mixing those steps is a recipe for disaster, especially when the data structure gets more complex.

Comment: You are right, I am a newbie and I am trying to write a code while I am learning, that's why my structure is terrible.

Comment: That's no problem, we all have to learn and I do not expect you to use an MVC framework for your first project. It's just that data is a lot easier to manipulate before you output it then during (or even after) output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution here is to create a query that retrieves all information at once, like so

```
SELECT N1.*, A1.ED_name addedby_name, A2.ED_name lasteditor_name FROM N1News AS N1
INNER JOIN A1Editors AS A1 ON N1.N1_Addedby=A1.Ed_ID
LEFT JOIN A1Editors AS A2 ON N1.N1_Lastedit=A2.Ed_ID
WHERE N1_Co=$Ed_Co
ORDER BY N1_ID
LIMIT $show,$limit
```

Note that this query assumes that each news item references an AddedBy editor. A reference to LastEdit is optional in this query.

Comment: I think I have to choose this one as an answer, cause it works like a charm without extra queries, and made me learn a new thing. Thanks Arjan!

Answer (score 1):

There are probably more efficient ways to combine your two queries, but a quick solution would be to use [`UNION`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html):

```
$query = "(SELECT * FROM N1News AS N1
            LEFT JOIN A1Editors AS A1 ON N1.N1_Addedby=A1.Ed_ID WHERE N1_Co=$Ed_Co ORDER BY N1_ID LIMIT $show,$limit)
          UNION
          (SELECT * FROM N1News AS N2
            LEFT JOIN A1Editors AS A2 ON N2.N1_Lastedit=A2.Ed_ID WHERE N1_Co=$Ed_Co ORDER BY N1_ID LIMIT $show,$limit)
          ORDER BY N1.N1_ID
```

That way you have al results in one array, making it easy to generate your table.

By the way, the `mysql_*` functions are deprecated and you should really switch to prepared statements in PDO or mysqli

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this. As you can imagine I am new in Php.

Comment: That query does return one result list, but it's more complex to determine if the editor information is about the creator or last editor. And each news item will appear twice in the list. The order in which they appear is random.

Comment: @Arjan It needs some fine-tuning (ordering is possible, see the manual) but it could work. It would probably be more clear and efficient using joins though.

Answer (score 0):

You can place second query into first while.

```
<?php
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM N1News AS N1
LEFT JOIN A1Editors AS A1 ON N1.N1_Addedby=A1.Ed_ID WHERE N1_Co=$Ed_Co ORDER BY N1_ID LIMIT $show,$limit");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
echo '<tr><td align="center">'.$row["N1_ID"].'</td><td><a href="news_edit2.php?n_id='.$row["N1_ID"].'">'.$row["N1_Title"].'</a></td>
    <td><a href="news_edit2.php?n_id='.$row['N1_ID'].'"><img src="images/icons/hammer_screwdriver.png" alt="Edit News" /></a><a href="news_del.php?n_id='.$row["N1_ID"].'"><img src="images/icons/cross.png" alt="Delete News" /></a></td><td>'.$row["Ed_Name"].'</td>';
    // call second query //
    $newsid = $row["N1_ID"];

    $query7 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM N1News AS N1
    LEFT JOIN A1Editors AS A1 ON N1.N1_Lastedit=A1.Ed_ID WHERE N1_ID = ".$newsid." AND N1_Co=$Ed_Co ORDER BY N1_ID LIMIT $show,$limit");

    if($row7 = mysql_fetch_array($query7)){
    echo '<td>'.$row7["Ed_Name"].'</td>';
    }
    /////////////////////

    }

?>
```

Comment: Executing queries inside a loop is generally a bad idea, because it quickly creates a lot of queries which will make the system slow.

Comment: I dont think that. Some times query inside query is more useful than all in one query. If you want to make quickly program, So you can change your programming language to another fast languages.